# Точка после переменной. Пример: $a.=$b[$i]; - ошибка или нет?

Tags: php

Копался в одном скрипте покупном и обнаружил примерно такую картину:

```
$a.=$b[$i];
```

Информации про точку после переменной в Google не нашел.
Думаю, это ошибка, но все же хотелось бы узнать мнение программистов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это точка не после переменной, а перед "равно") И нет, не ошибка, укороченный вариант конкатенации (сложения строк).

```
$a .= $b; // $a = $a . $b;
$x += $y; // $x = $x + $y;
$i /= 5; // $i = $i / 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a  = 1;
$a .= 2;
echo $a;
```

Так же используется! Часто в велосипедах)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, как известно, в языке php знак "." применяется для конкатенации, то есть соединения двух элементов в один. Получается, что

> ```
> $a  = 1;
> $a .= 2;
> echo $a;
> ```

**Выведет число 12*(т.к "1"."2"="12")***